# Iterating over list of JSON objects that have no root element

Tags: javascript, json, iterator

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete and the documentation states that the source can be a list of JSON objects. The code I have below does work but I noticed that the list of JSON objects does not have a root element.

```
<script>
  var availableTags = [];
  function populate() {
    var availableTags = [
      { label:"ActionScript", value: "1"},
      { label:"AppleScript", value: "2"},
      { label:"Asp", value: "3"}
      ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  };
</script>
```

I would like to find a way to iterate over this list of objects retrieving the "label" and "value" valuesbut I'm not sure how without the root element. Can someone point me in the right direction on this? I have tried formulating loops but I am stumped.

Thank you so very much in advance.
JW

Comment: I'm confused... or maybe you are? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? A root element is something that applies to a tree structure, but not to an array, which you can iterate over with a simple availableTags.forEach.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Why are there two `availabeTags` arrays? A global one that's empty and a local one with content.

Comment: `availableTags` is precisely a **list [array] of objects**

Comment: Thank you everyone for the above input. Not sure why I zoned on it being just a simple list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

availableTags is an array, and you can iterate as such:

```
for (var i=0;i<availableTags.length;i++) {
   var label = availableTags[i].label; 
   var value = availableTags[i].value;

   // ... do what you need to do with label and value.
}
```

Comment: Good lord, that was ridiculously simple. Accepted answer.